# .NET Framework 4.6.1 services.addSignalR and app.UseSignalR not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, .net-4.6.1

I am trying to create a Chatroom with SignalR. I know that there are many Samples out there but somehow it's not working with my .Net Framework application. We tried many soulutions because every toturial site has a different Walkthrough.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using Database;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace Chatroom
{
    public class Startup
    {



        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();    
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

           services.AddCors(options =>
           {
               options.AddPolicy("fiver",
                   policy => policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                                   .AllowAnyMethod());
           });

            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddSingleton<FanZContext, FanZContext>(x => new FanZContext());
            services.AddMvc();


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<SensorHub>("sensor");
            });


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });


        }



    }

}
```

Syntax Error: 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSignalR' and no extension method 'AddSignalR' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Linking a simple Sample project thats working on .Net Framework 4.6.1 would help to, i googled so many tutorials im desperate now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add the SignalR package?

Comment: Yes, I install the package the packages Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR, SignalR.Client and SignalR.JS.

Comment: If you build the project, do you have any other errors before that one? the code is perfect, it must be something related to the package or that package on .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: I don't know what exactly I did but it is working now. I am guessing it was a package conflict. I installed and uninstalled a SignalR package and somehow the errors disappeared.  Anyways Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix and match versions of the SignalR server and client

From the Alpha release blog post [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/)

> One of the consequences of this is that SignalR for ASP.NET Core is not compatible with previous versions of SignalR. This means that you cannot use the old server with the new clients or the old clients with the new server.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out by upgrading ASPNETCore to 2.1